# Flash Videos "Bleeding" above Lightbox Video

Tags: flash, lightbox, swfobject

Have a video in a lightbox on a page that has some other Flash content (banners, animation, etc. in SWFObject). I guess Flash has it's own window that's essentially on top of the document window (although I'm not sure I understand this in it's entirety). Tried setting wmode to transparent, and also tried several lightbox libraries (JQuery and also MooTools based, but NOT prototype yet). For now, we've resorted to temporarily opening in another tab which sucks!

Any suggestions or even knowledge that may help?

Comment: Did you try `wmode` on both the `param` and the `embed`?

Comment: Only on the param. I think it was so.addVariable("wmode","transparent") as I was using the SWFObject lib. Is embed in the original Flash? If so, I don't have access to source (but Flash developer will probably give me that if I need it). Can you give me more information?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common problem. Sometimes it can be solved using `wmode`, other times the solution seems more complicated. I found [somebody saying](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=23833):

> The trick is to position a transparent IFrame directly behind your floating div. The div will then appear above embedded Flash, SVG and select boxes[.]

[This forum post](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3164991&postcount=44) sums up a lot of the problems regarding this question, perhaps it's useful to you.

Comment: Yeah, I read the forum and that's why I tried the SWFObject addVariable (or whatever) to change the wmode...didn't work. I'll check out he IFrame solution and report back.